# Printf prints same variable value differently in successive calls without any operation done in between

Tags: c, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
//program start here
{

int i= 655535;
int *p =&i;
printf("p:%d \n*p:%d \n",p,*p);
printf("*p++:%d \n p:%d \n *p:%d \n ++(*p):%d \n p:%d \n",*p++, p,*p, ++*p,p);
printf("p:%d\n", p);
getch();
}
```

output:

```
p:2293620
*p:655535
*p++:655536
p:2293620
*p:655536
++(*p):655536
p:2293620
p:2293624
```

WHy do the above program print last  ' p ' values different ?

Comment: OT: Use `%p` and casting to `(void *)` to print pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parameters sent to function call are pushed in a stack in reverse order, so when it will pop the values to get them in the right order

in your case:

`printf("*p++:%d \n p:%d \n *p:%d \n ++(*p):%d \n p:%d \n",*p++, p,*p, ++*p,p);`

will do the following steps:

1) push `p` -> `p:2293620`

2) push `++*p` -> `++(*p):655536`

3) push `*p` -> `*p:655536`

4) push `p` -> `p:2293620`

5) push `*p++` same as `*(p++)` -> *p++:655536 // post increment operation will be visible only on the next print, and also you increment the pointer with the `sizeof(int)`

This explains why you have different values for p

for example for the following code snippet:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int a = 10;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", a++, a++, a++);
    return 0;
}
```

you will get the following output:

```
12 11 10
```

Comment: The C standard does not define the order in which arguments are evaluated, and C implementations typically do not define it either. Even if you have observed this in specific instances, it is not reliable, because optimization is likely to change evaluation order. If the arguments to a call contain compound expressions, such as `foo(a*b+c, d+e*f)`, and one of the expressions has recently been evaluated because the same expression appeared just prior to the call, the C implementation is likely to store that one on the stack first, then evaluate the other. There may also be partial evaluations.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, at the time I answered this I knew that from hearsay, now I just found this [ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkwh89ks.aspx ] related to argument passing order.

Answer (score 5):

```
*p++
```

is equivalent to:

```
*(p++)
```

so this changes `p`.

Your program invokes undefined behavior, because it modifies and accesses `p` and `*p` between sequence points, with all those increments and accesses in the second `printf` argument list. In the implementation you used, all the `p` accesses are done before the increment, it prints the unmodified value. However, `*p` is done after the increment, so it prints the modified value.

Comment: I don't think here is a problem related to sequence points as the comma operator introduces a sequence point, and the same value is't modified between them.

Comment: @pavel.lazar The comma between arguments to a function is not the same as the comma operator.

Answer (score 0):

You have a

> *(p++) == *p++

in this line:

> printf("*p++:%d \n p:%d \n *p:%d \n ++(*p):%d \n p:%d \n",*p++, p,*p,
>   ++*p,p);

The address that p points to will be incremented by **sizeof(int)*1** after the **printf** call returns.
So the final value of p is  **2293620 + 4*1=2293624**